# Unzipping an image failing using buffer from gzip format

Tags: java, gzip

I am zipping the files using , but while unzipping them, I am facing two problems,

1. when **unzipped without buffer its getting back to original form, but when I use buffer its not able to do it correctly**.
2. the **size of the unzipped file is more than the original file**.

```
private static void writeFile(FileOutputStream fos, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
                GZIPInputStream inflaterInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fis)) {
            int data;
            **while ((data = inflaterInputStream.read()) != -1) {//without buffer**
                fos.write(data);
            }
        }
    }

private static void writeFile(FileOutputStream fos, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12048];
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
                GZIPInputStream inflaterInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fis)) {
            int data;
            **while ((data = inflaterInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {//with buffer**
                fos.write(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not writing the `buffer`, but `data` which is the length of bytes read...

Corrected:

```
private static void writeFile(FileOutputStream fos, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[12048];
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
         InputStream inflaterInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fis)) {
         int data;
         while ((data = inflaterInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {//with buffer**
             fos.write(buffer, 0, data);
         }
    }
}
```

You'd be better off using `apache.commons-io`

```
private static void writeFile(FileOutputStream fos, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
         InputStream inflaterInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fis)) {
        IOUtils.copy(fis, fos);
    }
}
```